# Bounds on $\int \log(1+x) g(x) \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two continuous real random variables with common support $(0,x_{\max}]$ and with PDF $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$. Assume that $\Pr [Y\geq\beta \mid X<\beta] \leq k$ and that $\Pr [Y<\beta \mid X\geq\beta]  \leq k$ for any $\beta$ in the support of $X$ and $Y$, where $0 < k < 1$ is a constant. Consider function $Z(X) = \log(1+X)$.

What can we say on mean and variance of $Z(Y)$ based on the moments of $Z(X)$? Exact expressions, bounds?

Comment: Could you please describe a bit about the background of this problem?

Comment: Consider $Z(X)$ as a function of random variable $X>0$. Imagine that we are estimating random variable $X$ by another random variable, called $Y$, such as the false alarm and misdetection rates become less than $k$ w.r.t. any reference point $\beta$. We are interested to investigate distribution of $Z(Y)$ w.r.t. parameters of the distribution of $Z(X)$. This abstract problem shows itself in many applications such as wireless communications. In this problem, I asked for a simple example of $Z(X)=\log⁡(1+X)$ and characterizing average of $Z(Y)$ based on distribution of  $Z(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have better luck bounding the median of $Z(Y)$, or other quantiles and L-moments.

Let $Q_X$ and $Q_Y$ be the quantile functions for $X$ and $Y$.  Then
$Q_Y(p)$ is between $Q_X((p-k)/(1-k))$ and $Q_X(p/(1-k))$, and similarly for the $Z$'s.

As an example, say $k$ is 10%.  Then the median of log($Y$) is between the logs of the 44th and 56th percentiles of $X$.

Answer (score -1):

Besides some trivial lower bound because of the range constraint, there is not much you can say here. I can let $Y$ be $X$ with probability $> k$ for each $X$ value and anything else otherwise. There is a lot of freedom no matter how close $k$ is to $1$.

Comment: not clear to me how we can let $Y=X$ with probability higher $k$ for each $X$.

Comment: Define Y = X 1{Z < k} + W 1{Z>=k}, where Z is a uniform [0,1], X, W, Z mutually independent. By manipulating W you can get arbitrarily large moments for Y regardless of moments of X.

Comment: $Y=X \, \mathbb{1}_{Z<k} + W \, 1_{Z \geq k}$ will not necessarily ensure both $\Pr[Y\geq \beta \mid X<\beta] \leq k$ and $\Pr[Y< \beta \mid X \geq \beta] \leq k$.

Comment: My Y satisfies P(Y > X|X=x) < k for all little x. Now integrate over $x < \beta$. Same holds for the other inequality. What's your counterexample?

Comment: Can you first start by assuming $(X,Y)$ is bivariance Gaussian? Then you can look at a bivariate Lancaster family; then your problem relates to extremal points in the corresponding family. Without a joint distribution on $(X,Y)$, how can one get exact expression? Think about it this way: you are tying to expand a function in terms of the moments of another random variable.

Comment: Why the negative vote if some good samaritan took the pain to redact my answer?